# Add automatically alert when user/record is added to the list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online

I'm having a problem to automatically add alert. I have a list "ListA" where I add new records. This records have address email field. I try to create workflow which use this address email to send alerts. Without any positive results.

ListA - users
ListB - some records
ListC - other records

I want to user from ListA will be inform when something on ListB or ListC will be added, changed.

I this possible using only workflow?

Thanks, Ripperus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a custom SPItemEventReceiver that fires on the ItemAdded and ItemUpdated events on ListB and ListC.

public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    EmailUsersInListA();
}

public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    EmailUsersInListA();
}

The following link contains examples from MSDN showing how to add event recievers: [MSDN examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010.aspx)